# vscode quickSuggestions not working with Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For example there are two functions f1 and f2

```py
def f1(download_playlist):
    pass

def f2(download_playlist):
    print('download_playlist')
```

It is expected that after entering f1, the two download_playlists in f2 only need to enter the first few letters, and there will be download_playlist in the quick suggestion list, so that you don't have to type it from beginning to end every time

This setting doesn't work

```json
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
  },
  "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
```

Comment: Try adding this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: try to force suggestions with `Ctrl+Space` or `Ctrl+Shift+Space`, it does not always show when inside strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved Need to add the following settings

```json
  "[python]": {
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
  },
```